# How to display number of database inserts in a particular session in cgi perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I have an assignment which requires us to create a quiz form  in perl cgi accepting new questions from our local web browser. Each insertion of question need to be updated in state table, and at the end should display number of questions exists in database as well as new questions inserted at each session.I used HTML for forms and Mysql as my database and running on localhost. My state table has columns id, qnumber,last_modified,new_quest.
    Here is my code i have implemented so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

if ($ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} eq "POST") {
  read(STDIN, $datastring, $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"});     
}
elsif (exists $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"}) {     # data from GET transaction (or HEAD or other)
  $datastring = $ENV{"QUERY_STRING"};
}
else {
  print "Offline execution detected\n";
  print "Please enter some data.\n";
  $datastring = <>;
  chomp $datastring;
  print "== data accepted == HTML output follows ==\n\n";
}

###decode######################################################
$datastring =~s/%0D%0A/\n/g;                            #step to deal with line
                                #breaks in text areas
@nameValuePairs = split(/&/, $datastring);          #step 1
foreach $pair (@nameValuePairs) {
  ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);              #step 2

  $name =~tr/+/ /;                                      #step 3
  $name =~s/%([\da-fA-F]{2})/pack("C",hex($1))/eg;      #step 3
  $value =~tr/+/ /;                                     #step 3
  $value =~s/%([\da-fA-F]{2})/pack("C",hex($1))/eg;     #step 3

  if(exists $formHash{$name}) {                 #improved step 4,
    $formHash{$name} = $formHash{$name}.";".$value;     #now handles multiple
  }                             #select menus
  else {
    $formHash{$name} = $value;
  }     
}
###done decoding###############################################

### global variables ##########################################
use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
$dbhandle = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:databasexx", "idxx", "passxx")  
    or &errorPage("Can't connect to database". DBI->errstr()); 
$file_life_span = 1.0/24; # in days (so is 1 hours)
$time_out = 1.0/24; # in days
$cache_limit = 300;
$state_table_name = "xyz";  # name of state table
$quiz_table_name = "xyzz";     # name of quiz table
%stateHash=();
### end of global variables #####################################

### app logic ###################################################
if($formHash{"request"} eq "begin_quiz") {
    &begin_quiz;
}
elsif($formHash{"id"} eq "SessionId") {
    &enter_question;
}
else {
    &welcome_page;
}
### end app logic ################################################


##################################################################
sub welcome_page {
 print <<PAGE;
 <html><head><title>Trivia Quiz</title></head>
  <body>
   <h2>Welcome to the Trivia Quiz</h2>
 You will be asked to enter questions for quiz.
    <form action="$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="GET">
     <input type="hidden" name="request" value="begin_quiz">
     <input type="submit" value="Begin Quiz">
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
PAGE
}

##################################################################

sub begin_quiz {
 my $sessionID = &get_long_id_db($dbhandle, $state_table_name, $cache_limit, $file_life_span);
 %stateHash = ("qnumber"=>1, "new_quest"=>0);
 &write_state_db($dbhandle, $state_table_name, $sessionID, %stateHash);

 print <<TOP;
 <html><head><title>Trivia Quiz Salwa</title></head>
  <body>
   Enter your questions now: <br/>
TOP
print<<FORM;
<br/>
<form action = "$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="GET">
     <br/>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$sessionID"/>
   Number:<input type="text" name="qnumber" value=qnumber/><br>
   Question:<input type= "text" name= "question" value=question/><br>
   Choice 1:<input type= "radio" name="choices1" value=choice1 checked/></br>
   Choice 2:<input type ="radio" name ="choices2" value=choice2/> </br>
   Choice 3:<input type="radio" name ="choices3" value=choice3/></br>
   Choice 4:<input type ="radio" name= "choices4" value=choice4/></br>
   Choice 5:<input type="radio" name="choices5" value=choice5/></br>
   Answer:<input type="text" name="answer" value=answer/></br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit answer"/>
   </form>
FORM

 &enter_question($sessionID,1);

 print <<BOTTOM;
 </body>
</html>
BOTTOM
}
#################################################################
sub enter_question{
my ($sessionID,$new_quest) = @_;

$question= $formdata{'question'};
$qnumber= $formdata{'qnumber'};
$answer= $formdata{'answer'};
$choice1= $formdata{'choice1'};
$choice2= $formdata{'choice2'};
$choice3= $formdata{'choice3'};
$choice4= $formdata{'choice4'};
$choice5= $formdata{'choice5'};

print ("<html><head><title>Add questions</title></head>\n");
print ("<body>\n");

<form action = "$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}" method="GET">
my $sql ="insert into $quiz_table_name(qnumber,question,answer,choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4,choice5) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
my $qObj = $dbhandle->prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare");
my $qObj -> execute("$qnumber", "$question", "$answer", "$choice1", "$choice2", "$choice3", "$choice4", "$choice5") 
or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
print " Question $qnumber was added to database.";
$new_quest++;

print ("</form></body></html>\n");
$qObj->finish();
$dbhandle->disconnect();
}

#################################################################
#################################################################
# end app logic functions####
# begin toolkit functions######
#################################################################
#################################################################

#################################################################
sub write_state_db {
  my ($dbhandle, $table_name, $sessionID, %states) = @_;
  ### add the updated last-modified time to the front of the incoming state hash
  my $currtime = time;
  my @updates = ("last_modified = '$currtime'");
  foreach $key (keys %states){
    push @updates, "$key = '$states{$key}'";
  }

  ###  update the state record
  $sql = "UPDATE $table_name set " . join(",", @updates) . " WHERE id = '$sessionID'";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql);
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> finish();
}

#################################################################
sub read_state_db {
  my ($dbhandle, $table_name, $sessionID, $time_out, 
        $time_out_function, $time_out_message) = @_;   ### $time_out is in days

  ### read the desired state record into the query object
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE ID = '$sessionID'";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  my $rowhashref = $qObj->fetchrow_hashref();
  $qObj -> finish();

  if(! $rowhashref) { ### $rowhashref is an empty reference, which means no such id...
    &errorPage("No such session.");
  }
  my %hash = %$rowhashref;  ### get the actual hash containing the state record
  ### timeout test
  if(($time_out > 0) && ($hash{"last_modified"} < time - $time_out*24*60*60)){ 
    ### timed out...
    if($time_out_function) {
      &$time_out_function($time_out_message);
            exit;
    }
        else{
        &errorPage("Your session has timed out");
    }
  }
  ### touch the record
  $sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET last_modified = " . time . " WHERE ID = '$sessionID'";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> finish();
  ### only need to return the actual state data
  delete $hash{"id"};
  delete $hash{"last_modified"};
  return %hash;           
}

#################################################################
sub get_long_id_db {
  my ($dbhandle, $table_name, $cache_limit, $file_life_span) = @_;

  ### count number of sessions
  my $sql = "SELECT id FROM $table_name";  
  my $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());
  $qObj -> fetchall_arrayref(); 

  if($qObj->rows() >= $cache_limit) {       ### Need to police table?
    my $expiredtime = int(time - $file_life_span*24*60*60); ### in seconds ###
    $qObj -> finish();

    ### police the table
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE last_modified < $expiredtime";
    $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");;
    $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr()); 
    $qObj -> finish();

    ### count number of sessions again
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM $table_name";        
    $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");;
    $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr()); 
    $qObj -> fetchall_arrayref(); 

    if($qObj->rows() >= $cache_limit) { ### still over limit?
      # should generate e-mail message to warn administrator
      &errorPage("Site busy. Please try again later.");
    }
  }
  $qObj -> finish();

  my $id = &generate_random_string(32);
  my $currtime = time;

  ### create new state record
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, last_modified) values ('$id', $currtime)";
  $qObj = $dbhandle -> prepare($sql) or &errorPage("Can't prepare.");;
  $qObj -> execute() or &errorPage("Can't execute " . $qObj->errstr());

  return $id;
}

#################################################################
sub generate_random_string {
  my $n = $_[0];
  my $result = "";
  my @chars = (0..9, 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z');
  my $which;
  for($i = 1 ; $i <= $n ; $i++) {
    $which=int rand 62;
   $result = $result . $chars[$which];
  }
  return $result;
}

#################################################################
sub errorPage {
 my $message = $_[0]; # the incoming parameter, store in localized variable
 print<<ALL;
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Error encountered</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Error Encountered</h1>
  <h3>$message</h3>
  Please try again, or report the problem to the webmaster.
 </body>
 </html>
ALL
 exit;
}
```

This is my first encounter with this language and i worked on this script so much that now i am confused and lost track of what should be tried next to get this thing run. Can anyone find the problem with this script.

Comment: `$qObj->rows` will show the affected rows count after the execute.  http://www.perlhowto.com/dbi_get_the_number_of_rows_affected_by_a_sql_statement

Comment: @Anthony that resource is wrong. While the general idea is correct, there are syntax errors on that tutorial.

Comment: Fair enough. Here's the documentation on the `rows` property, from the manual : https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#rows

Comment: If this is your first work with Perl, you should switch the tutorials you are learning from as soon as possible. You are doing Perl in a way that was common (yet not very good) about 15 years ago. If you care to do it properly and in a way that will be way easier to maintain, please take a look at the websites and books linked in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info). Start by reading up on `use strict` and `use warnings`. Don't use global variables, indent your code and fix the other syntax errors. Right now it doesn't even compile.

Comment: I second what @simbabque says about your Perl style. [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) lists some better ways to write CGI programs and the [Perl Tutorial Hub](http://perl-tutorial.org/) will point you at some higher quality Perl tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute),

> For a *non*-`SELECT` statement, `execute` returns the number of rows affected, if known. If no rows were affected, then `execute` returns "0E0", which Perl will treat as 0 but will regard as true. Note that it is *not* an error for no rows to be affected by a statement. If the number of rows affected is not known, then `execute` returns -1.

So, if you change `$qObj->execute...` to `my $rv = $qObj->execute...`, then `$rv` will contain the number of rows affected (when executing `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or other non-`SELECT` statements).  This will allow you to immediately tell the user "you just inserted `$rv` questions into the database" after a form submission.

However, I suspect that your assignment actually wants the program to be able to show the total number of questions inserted by a session (identified by `$sessionID` in your existing code), not just the number added by an individual form submission.  The way to do *that* is to add a `session_id` column to the database and populate it with the value of `$sessionID` when inserting questions.  You can then `SELECT count(*) FROM $quiz_table_name GROUP BY session_id` to get a list of all sessions and the number of questions inserted by each.

Finally, some standard Perl advice for beginners:

- *Always* start your programs with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, then fix everything they complain about.  They're excellent debugging tools and help you to write better code.  If the complaints are too cryptic for you to understand, you can also `use diagnostics;` to get more verbose/detailed messages.
- Interpolating variables directly into your SQL statements makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  If you think you're likely to use Perl much in the future, get into the habit of using SQL placeholders instead.  Consider using placeholders even if not, especially if your instructor is at all security-conscious.  See [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more information about this, including examples of how to use placeholders in Perl (and several other languages).
- The `CGI` module has methods for reading and decoding the data received from the web server.  You're generally better off using them than inspecting `%ENV` by hand.  (You'd be even better off using a proper web framework, such as Dancer, Mojolicious, or Catalyst, but I assume that would fall outside of your assignment's boundaries.)
- Don't use an `&` prefix when making function calls.  (e.g., use `begin_quiz()`, not `&begin_quiz`)  The prefix is a holdover from Perl 4 which is no longer needed in Perl 5.  Aside from looking less pleasant, it also has side-effects that you probably don't need or want.